# Javascript OOP in Angular not updating new object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

So I'm new to OOP in javascript, and I'm working on an angularjs site. I have an object being created, and my object methods change the properties, but the propeties are only being changed in the class and not the new object.

```
//Class
Var Item = function() {
  this.currentItem = 1;
}

Item.prototype.itemUp = function(){
  this.currentItem++;
}

//New Object
item = new Item();
$scope.currentItem = item.currentItem;
item.itemUp();
```

After doing some debugging, I realized that this code updates the Item.currentItem, but not the item.currentItem

```
console.log(item.currentItem) --> 1
console.log(Item.currentItem) --> 2
```

How to I make the class method modify the new created object, and not the class itself?

Thanks,

Comment: You have 'currentItem' and 'itemNumber', it's confusing to read your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$scope.item = new Item();
$scope.item.itemUp();
```

The error here is, i believe, that `item.currentItem` itself is not a reference, but the number itself.

Comment: I think he should do this instead: `$scope.currentItem = item;`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
//Class
var Item = function() {
    this.itemNumber = 1;
}

Item.prototype.itemUp = function(){
    this.itemNumber++;
}

//New Object
item = new Item();
$scope.currentItem = item;
item.itemUp();
```